# DDD: caching aggregate objects that received from sever

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

Suppose I have a repository `(ContactsRepository)` with method like `getAllContacts(userId)`.
The `(ContactsRepository)` fetch all data from server. After first call `getAllContacts(userId)` method I want to cache this data. My question is where I should realize caching mechanism, in the same `(ContactsRepository)` and when I invoke `getAllContacts(userId)` method again the repository back my caching data or I need put the data into another place (maybe Repository).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Repository to obtain the data either from the cache or from the database. if your Repository classes have update methods you can effectively invalidate the cache items as well.

You can thus encapsulate the access to cache within the Repository:
http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html

Another example to implement caching for Repository:
http://ardalis.com/building-a-cachedrepository-via-strategy-pattern

Comment: Thx for the answer, I have already realized that like in your second link.

Answer (score 1):

You can cache it, but don't forget [cache coherency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) if you execute domain logic with more than one repository, e.g. on multiple machines.